# Is this the right way to initialize a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Is this the right way to use a function that writes to a pointer? Do I have to allocate memory for the `double*` before calling the function?

```
double *myDouble;
write_to_pointer( myDouble );
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to "allocate" memory. You must make sure the pointer points to a `double` object that you can write to.

Comment: @juanchopanza I suppose it doesn't in my example?

Comment: Right, the pointer doesn't point anywhere good. Trying to de-reference it would be *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @Anna In your example the pointer has not been initialized and hence, it does not point to any valid memory location. Thus, the write would fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make pointers point to data in a variety of ways.

The following will create a single double on the heap, and will be pointed to by `myDub`. It will then assign the value of `myDub` to 4. It will then delete `myDub` and set the pointer to `NULL`.

```
double * myDub = new double;
*myDub = 4;
delete myDub;
myDub = NULL;
```

You can similarly allocate arrays.

```
double * myDub = new double[123];
myDub[0] = 4;
myDub[3] = 43;
delete[] myDub;
myDub = NULL;
```

And you can have pointers point to variables that already exist. (Note that I don't call delete in this case!)

```
double onStack = 4;
double * myDub = &onStack;
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean it writes to the pointer itself, or to the memory it points to?

If it's the first, and it takes the pointer by reference, for example:

```
void write_to_pointer(double *& p) {
    p = whatever;
}
```

then it's correct, although rather confusing. It would be better to return the value as a return value, so that the assignment is more obvious:

```
double *get_pointer() {return whatever;}
double *myDouble = get_pointer();
```

If it's the second, then no: the pointer doesn't point at anything, so attempting to dereference it will give undefined behaviour (typically crashing or corrupting some other program memory). It will need to point to a valid `double` (or a sufficiently large array of `double`, if that's what the function expects).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the latter. Should I use `new` to make it point somewhere? Is it OK to do it this way? `double myDouble[3] = {0,0,0}`? (if it expects space for a three-element double array)

Comment: @Anna Yes, it's fine to point to any array. There's no need to use `new` unless you need dynamic allocation for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to write to a pointer. Either allocate memory to your variable:

```
double *myDouble =  new double;
write_to_pointer( &myDouble );
delete myDouble;
```

in this case declaration will be write_to_pointer( double** )

OR

declare your variable on stack:

```
double myDouble;
write_to_pointer( &myDouble );
```

in this case declaration will be write_to_pointer( double* )